# Interpretation of the weighted portmanteau Li-Mak test for ARCH effects

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, garch

From the literature I do not understand the null hypothesis of this test. I used it's implementation in R to confirm my multivariate model captures the ARCH effects present in the data. I use this line of code:

```
Weighted.LM.test(fit1@model$residuals[,1], fit1@model$sigma[,1]^2, lag = 25,type = c("correlation", "partial"),fitdf = 1, weighted = TRUE)
```

To obtain the standardized residuals and put them in the test. The results are:

```
Weighted X-squared on Squared Residuals for fitted ARCH process = 5.1043, Shape = 9.5018, Scale = 1.3640, p-value = 0.8705
```

Does the *p*value indicate I fail to reject the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation, and therefore there is still autocorrelation present, and thus my model is flawed? Or am I misinterpreting this test. Any recommendations on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $p$-value is high, so you do not reject $H_0$ of no autocorrelation in squared standardized residuals. No autocorrelation is what you want as the model assumes the standardized innovations to be i.i.d. All looks fine.

Comment: Thank you Richard for the confirmation. It seems I indeed misinterpreted and am glad that my model is adequate.

The LM function is from a specific package:
`A weighted portmanteau test for testing the null hypothesis of adequately fitted ARCH process. This is essentially a weighted version of the statistic proposed by Li and Mak (1994)`, as proposed by Fisher and Gallagher (2012).

Comment: @Guest, thanks for correcting me. I have updated my answer accordingly.